# Why do the recent reviewers get squeezed after 20 reviews?

Tags: support, review, ios

After I complete 20 reviews on a single day for some review queue, I typically see a message similar to this example (for the First Posts):

> Thank you for reviewing 20 first posts today; come back in 6 hours to continue reviewing.

However, after the recent changes to the Review page, the images of the 6 most recent reviewers of that review queue will look like in this sample:

[image]

Note how, in the above image, for the "first posts" review queue, the 6 profile pictures seem to be squeezed to the right: their entire width is like about the width of 5 profile pictures for any of the other review queues where I didn't complete 20 reviews yet.

This happens to me on an iOS device (running 9.3.5), and this in about 5 different SE sites and/or review queues over the past few days. No idea so far how it looks like in the most recent iOS version.

***How nice, merci beaucoup!!!***, I refuse to believe that this is the new way to say "merci for all those reviews today", is it? ... I hope this is rather an *undocumented feature*, aka bug.

PS: Looking at the same review page around the same time on a Win PC (using any of the common browsers) seems to work fine, no matter which width I use for my browser window.

Comment: Oh, now I see it. I think you should put a red circle or at least say what the problem is, because it's not immediately obvious.

Comment: @TheWanderer better with my edited version (the "note"-parg I added below the image)?

Comment: Not only the icons have the wrong size, also the word `First Posts` etc are too small

Comment: @samcarter you're right, but I didn't want to mix different issues in the same question (1 issue at a time). And by the way, there are even other issues I think that are worth (at least) a discussion ...

Comment: We just updated this page. I'm guessing it's a bug. :) Thanks for pointing it out! Hopefully we can look at it next week.